# How can I enable geoIP on Chrome / Firefox? Services like ipinfo are getting blocked on Chrome and Firefox, but work in Brave

Tags: cors, ip, coordinates, fetch-api, geoip

On page load, I'm trying to fetch coordinates based on visitor IP, with a service like ipinfo:

```
const request = await fetch("https://ipinfo.io/json?token=TOKEN", {
    method: 'GET',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "charset": "utf-8"
});
```

This works as expected in Brave.  In Chrome, the request is "blocked by client."  In Firefox, the request fails due to CORS.

Adding a cors-anywhere url isn't viable either, as it returns the location coordinates of the cors-anywhere url service (instead of the visitor).

How can I get geoIP working on Chrome and Firefox?  Are there any services that tend to work better for this — especially for development environments, where requests are coming from `localhost`?

Comment: You should try removing everything in the fetch payload and just call with a simple URL. Most of the settings you are passing like method,allow,accept charset are not needed for your request.

Comment: And Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in fetch won’t do anything. It’s meant to be set on the server side to allow CORS

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by fetching the visitor's IP first, using api.ipify.org (with a cors-anywhere url in front of it), and then inserting the ip address into the fetch query for ip info.  Here's the code:

```
const ip = await fetch("https://[CORS-ANYWHERE-URL]/https://api.ipify.org?format=json&callback=getIP");

const ip_json = await ip.json();
console.log(ip_json);

const request = await fetch(`https://[CORS-ANYWHERE-URL]/ipinfo.io/${ip_json["ip"]}/geo?token=TOKEN`, {
    method: 'GET',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "charset": "utf-8"
});
```